# datatable does not export all rows in a dataset in Rshiny

Tags: r, datatables, shiny, dt

I just noticed that `datatable` from `DT` library does not export all rows in the underlying dataset. It exports only visible rows. In the following reproducible example, it returns only 25 rows which are visible by default.

I wonder if there is any workaround to fix this.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

## Data table output format
data_output <- function(df) {
  DT::datatable(df, rownames= FALSE, options = list( dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = c('excel','pdf','print','colvis'), pageLength = 25, initComplete = DT::JS(
    "function(settings, json) {",
    "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#369BE9', 'color': '#fff'});",
    "}") ), 
    extensions = c('Buttons','FixedColumns'))
}

## Shiny UI
ui <- basicPage(
  h2("The mtcars data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

## Shiny Server
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    data_output(iris)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
## Data table output format
  data_output <- function(df) {
       DT::datatable(df, rownames= FALSE, options = list( dom = 'Bfrtip', buttons = c('excel','pdf','print','colvis'), pageLength = nrow(df), initComplete = DT::JS(
"function(settings, json) {",
"$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#369BE9', 'color': '#fff'});",
"}") ), 
extensions = c('Buttons','FixedColumns'))
}
```

Comment: This will also show all rows.. How can I just show the 10 rows at a time, but when exported to csv/excel, I get the whole dataset?

Comment: @SeGa what about DeanAttali's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50508854/button-extension-to-download-all-data-or-only-visible-data)