# Button extension to download all data or only visible data

Tags: r, shiny, dt

With the button extension to DT package, is there a way to specify that the buttons download either (1) all the data feeding the datatable, or (2) only the data on the visible page.

Below is the example from the [documentation](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html).

```
datatable(
  iris, extensions = 'Buttons', options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print')
  )
)
```

Comment: The buttons already do the second thing. Just hit the copy-Button when you type 'setosa' in the searchbar. and if you don't apply any filter you get the first. So I do not see what the issue here is

Answer (score 18, accepted):

See this answer: [Buttons: download button with scroller downloads only few rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477345/dt-buttons-download-button-with-scroller-downloads-only-few-rows?rq=1)

Whether the buttons export all data or only visible data is determined by the `server` argument in the `DT::renderDT` function call. If `server=FALSE` then the buttons will export all data in the table, while if `server=TRUE` they will only export visible data.

You could set the `server` argument with a variable to make this a selectable option.

```
output$table <- DT::renderDT(server = input$download_all, {
    DT::datatable( ... )
}
```

The other option you might want to look at is the `exportOptions: modifier: selected` option that determines whether to download only selected rows (the default) or all rows. You can read about that option here: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/select.html

Note that your users might run into performance and memory issues using `server=FALSE` if your data table is very large.

Answer (score 30):

As @divibisan said, one option is to use the `server` argument of `renderDT()` to control whether the download button will download only the current or all rows.

That would work well if you want to have one download button. However if you want to have two buttons always appear, where one download the current page and one downloads the full dataset, you can use the following code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDT(server = FALSE, {
    DT::datatable(
      mtcars,
      extensions = c("Buttons"),
      options = list(
        dom = 'Bfrtip',
        buttons = list(
          list(extend = "csv", text = "Download Current Page", filename = "page",
               exportOptions = list(
                 modifier = list(page = "current")
               )
          ),
          list(extend = "csv", text = "Download Full Results", filename = "data",
               exportOptions = list(
                 modifier = list(page = "all")
               )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi DeanAttali, this solution doesn't work on my end. When I click on Download Full Results is still download data for a single page. Any thoughts? Could it be because mine is a renderDataTable? or because I have extensions = c("Buttons","FixedColumns") ?

Comment: Nobody can answer that without seeing your code, but you should try to copy the exact code I have in my answer to determine if you're doing something wrong or not. If the exact code I provided has a different behaviour for you, then something with the package is wrong.

Comment: Hi @DeanAttali this solution works really well, thanks. However this doesn't work when used in shiny modules. Not sure, but I guess something to do with namespace for the Buttons extension

Comment: That's not my experience, I believe it works in modules. If you think it does not, then you should create a minimal reproducible example showing that this functionality is broken in modules, and submit it as an issue to the package.

Comment: @DeanAttali it totally works in modules too. My bad, missed the `server = FALSE` part

Comment: Its the way you answered the question, "That would work well". You should say, "That does work". You must have `server = FALSE` to get the whole data set.

Comment: This looks really helpful - is there a way to limit the number of rows to download (say 10,000?)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to include the options to download the current page and the entire dataset as both a csv or an excel file, I've managed to implement this as two separate dropdown buttons with those options, together with the copy and print buttons:

[image]

Here is the modified working code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(server = FALSE, {
    DT::datatable(
      mtcars,
      extensions = "Buttons",
      filter = "top",
      selection = "none", #this is to avoid select rows if you click on the rows
      rownames = FALSE,
      
      options = list(
        
        scrollX = TRUE,
        autoWidth = FALSE,
        dom = 'Blrtip', # the important thing is that there is the l to allow for the lengthMenu 
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645959/r-datatables-do-not-display-buttons-and-length-menu-simultaneously
        
        buttons = list(
          
          # insert buttons with copy and print
          # colvis includes the button to select and view only certain columns in the output table
          # from https://rstudio.github.io/DT/extensions.html 
          I('colvis'), 'copy', 'print',
          
          # code for the first dropdown download button
          # this will download only the current page only (depends on the number of rows selected in the lengthMenu)
          # using modifier = list(page = "current")
          # only the columns visible will be downloaded using the columns:":visible" option from:
          # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72317260/how-to-download-only-the-selected-columns-in-a-dataframe-using-colvis-from-dt-in/72317607#72317607
          list(
            extend = 'collection',
          buttons = list(
          list(extend = "csv", filename = "page",exportOptions = list(
            columns = ":visible",modifier = list(page = "current"))
          ),
          list(extend = 'excel', filename = "page", title = NULL, 
               exportOptions = list(columns = ":visible",modifier = list(page = "current")))),
          text = 'Download current page'),
          
          # code for the  second dropdown download button
          # this will download the entire dataset using modifier = list(page = "all")
          list(
            extend = 'collection',
            buttons = list(
              list(extend = "csv", filename = "data",exportOptions = list(
                columns = ":visible",modifier = list(page = "all"))
              ),
              list(extend = 'excel', filename = "data", title = NULL, 
                   exportOptions = list(columns = ":visible",modifier = list(page = "all")))),
            text = 'Download all data')
          
        ),
        # add the option to display more rows as a length menu
        lengthMenu = list(c(10, 30, 50, -1),
                          c('10', '30', '50', 'All'))
        ),
      class = "display"
      )
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 5):

you are looking for the `modifiers: page: selected`.  here is a working example

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = "Examples of DataTables",
  sidebarLayout(
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        id = 'dataset',
        tabPanel("diamonds", DT::dataTableOutput("mytable1"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  # choose columns to display
  diamonds2 = diamonds[sample(nrow(diamonds), 1000), ]
  output$mytable1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(diamonds2,
                  extensions = 'Buttons',
                  options = list(
                    dom = 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons = 
                      list(
                        list(
                        extend = 'csv',
                        buttons = c('csv'),
                        exportOptions = list(
                          modifiers = list(page = "current")
                        )
                      ))
                    )
                  )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

hope this helps!

Comment: The code provided doesn't run, and I believe that it would only print the current page even without the options you added.

Comment: I don't think `modifiers = list(page = "all")` does anything useful unless `server = FALSE`. And as @DeanAttali points out, I don't think `modifiers = list(page = "current")`actually changes any default behavior when `server = TRUE` (the default).