# How to make datatable ellipsis plugin work with full data download button?

Tags: javascript, r, datatables, dt

Trying to make use of the [DT](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/) package within a R/Shiny app, and running into a bit of an issue.

I'd like to make use of the [ellipsis plugin](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/dataRender/ellipsis), as well as a [custom button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59640310) to download **all** the data (DT default is to just download the current page shown).

See code below:

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris,
          rownames = F,
          extensions = "Buttons",
          plugins = "ellipsis",
          selection = 'none',
          options = list( dom = 'Bfrtip',
                         searching = F,
                         processing = F,
                         pageLenth = 20,
                         buttons = list(
                           list(extend = "csv", text = "Download Full Results", filename = "Full_data",
                                exportOptions = list(
                                  modifier = list(page = "all")
                                )
                           )
                         ),
                         columnDefs = list(list(
                           targets = c(4),
                           render = JS("$.fn.dataTable.render.ellipsis( 5 )")
                         )))

)
```

This displays fine, but when you press the 'Download Full Results" button and open in Excel, the ellipsis are rendered to weird/unfamilar characters ( â€¦ ). Ideally, I'd like the download button to ignore the ellipses. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works if you add the option `orthogonal = "export"` to `exportOptions`:

```
buttons = list(
  list(extend = "csv", text = "Download Full Results", filename = "Full_data",
       exportOptions = list(
         modifier = list(page = "all"),
         orthogonal = "export"
       )
  )
)
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. I figured it was something nested deep in the DataTables options.